# Django ordering by two fields not working as expected

Tags: django, sql-order-by

i am working on a shop for clothes, shoes etc. And i am trying to sort the products by price. The problems comes when the product's discount_price field is populated which means that this product is discounted. So when i want to order the products in my view i am expecting to see products with lower discount_price before products with higher price, but it is not working like this.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    discount_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The query i am performing

```
items = Item.objects.all().order_by('price', 'discount_price')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`Coalesce(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to first sort by `'discount_price'` if it is not `NULL`, and use `price` otherwise:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

items = Item.objects.order_by(Coalesce('discount_price', 'price').asc())
```